# determine general solution for this linear system

Tags: gaussian-elimination

[lateX of linear system to view more clearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od9Bt.png)

I have find a general solution to this linear system (included a link to lateX pic):

x_1 - 2x_2 + x_3 - 3x_4 = 1

2x_1 - 4x_2 + 4x_3 + 6x_4 + 4x_5 = 6

-2x_1 + 4x_2 - x_3 - 6x_4 + 2x_5 = 0

1x_1 - 2x_2 - 3x_3 + 3x_3 - 8x_5 = -7

But I end up getting :

x_1 - 2x_2 + x_3 + 3x_4 = 1

x_3 + 2x_5 = 2

Rank(Matrix) = 2

Basic Variables = x_1 x_3

Free Variables = x_2 x_4 x_5

I am unfamiliar with a matrix of this size only yielding two viable rows to work with. Should I proceed in setting the free variables equal to arbitrary numbers and solving for x_1 and x_3 to find the general solution? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a typo in the last line?

Comment: Sorry, which last line are you referring to? The given linear system or my answer?

Comment: No, the last line in your system.

Comment: I think it must be $$x_1-2x_2-3x_3+3x_4-8x_5=-7$$

Comment: Oh nuts, it is supposed to be -7